# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{b_n}$ converge then If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n*b_n}$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My attempt;

*Since $a_n$ converges then its sequence of partial sums $(x_n)$ converges to a limit x. Also, since $b_n$ converges then its sequence of partial sums $(y_n)$ converges to a limit y. Observe that by using the multiplication limit theorem:
If $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$ then $x_n*y_n \to x*y$. We know that the product of its partials sums converge, thus the product of the series converges.$*

Is this correct? Any guidance is appreciated !

Comment: If $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k$ it is **not** true that $x_ny_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k$. So the fact that $x_ny_n$ converges does help you.

Comment: In particular, this theorem isn't true in general, although it is true if $\sum|a_n|$ and $\sum|b_n|$ converges.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706246/prove-that-if-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-converges-and-b-n-infty-n-1-i?rq=1) for the correct version of the theorem.

Comment: If both sequences are non-negative, then you can argue that: because $\sum a_n$ converges, $a_n\rightarrow 0$; and so eventually $0 \le a_n \le 1$; and so eventually $0 \le a_n b_n \le b_n$; and so $\sum a_n b_n$ converges by comparison with $\sum b_n$.

Answer (score 6):

It is not generally true.  For example, take $a_n=b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$.

Clearly, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converge (Apply Leibniz's test for alternating series).

But, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true in general. there is a easy conterexample:

Regard $a_n =b_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ then $a_nb_n = \frac{1}{n}$.
you can use [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to check the convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n$ but $\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_nb_n = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n}$ will not converge!

if you assume a little bit more you can fix that!

Either if one is $a_n$ or $b_n$ is monoton then you can  [dirichlets test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) or if one converge absolute then you can use holder inequality:

$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n\right| \leq \sup|a_n|\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|$